# elements being covered by p5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I'm using p5 to create a canvas where I can draw stuff but when I tried to place text under it, it was always behind the canvas. I was able to resolve this for my laptop only by changing width and height artificially on the css file. The fix only works well for my laptop.

I placed the p5 canvas element inside a div in the HTML file but when I look at the elements tab in the dev tool on chrome, it says the div height is equal to 0. I have a feeling that it is because the HTML loads first before the js? I'm using userWidth for my createCanvas(). Shown below:

```
function setup() {
  const canvas = createCanvas(userWidth, userWidth/1.8).center('horizontal');
  canvas.parent('canvas');
}
```

HTML file (under body tag):

```
<div id = 'canvas'>
  <!-- canvas will go here -->
</div>
<div>
  <p id = 'textarea'>
    <!-- text added using DOM innerHTML -->
  </p>
</div>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "tried to place text under it" - where / how are you adding this text?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add, sorry about that. I'm adding text using innerHTML to add text to another <div> tag which is under the canvas div in the HTML file. Will change the original question

Comment: It would also help if you added a runnable example of your issue (Stack Overflow allows you to embed code-snippets which you can run your code in - see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) - or you could add a runnable example of your issue in the [p5js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/).

Comment: oh ok I'll do that.

Comment: I tried the p5js web editor but it's unsimilar to my problem since I'm using a separate HTML file which might have loaded first and may not have taken the width and height of the createCanvas function. Does p5.js work with the snippet?

Comment: You should be able to change when sketch.js loads by moving `<script src="sketch.js"></script>` in the web editor on the HTML page. If you want, you can use p5js with the code-snippet by including in the HTML using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>` and `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for all your comments! I ended up fixing it by placing all the other divs with text in the same div as the canvas. I'm not really sure why that worked but it does.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up placing the 'div' and 'p' tag for the text in the same div as the canvas. I'm not really sure why that worked but it did. I still had to edit the top-padding of the CSS file to mimic the ratio of width to height, with the width being 100%.

Comment: This answer is not exactly responsive. It works really well for google chrome on laptop but not for safari or chrome on iPad. This question is definitely still open to answers.